# Polynomial Multiplication using divide and conquer

Tags: python, algorithm, polynomials

I'm trying to write code that performs polynomial multiplication using a divide and conquer method. It uses a trick to do only 3 multiplications instead of 4 multiplications, involving splitting each polynomial into two halves and factoring out an x^n/2 from one of the two halves. My code is returning the wrong answer with some test cases and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit:** Adding naive multiply function and test cases.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
class Polynom:
    """stores polynomial object"""

    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        """pass coefficient list in increasing order, i.e. x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + ... + x^n"""
        self.coefficients = coefficients
        self.length = len(coefficients)
        self.nonZero = np.count_nonzero(self.coefficients)

    def __add__(self, other):
        for i in range(0,other.length):
            try:
                self.coefficients[i] = self.coefficients[i] + other.coefficients[i]
            except:
                self.coefficients.append(0)
                self.coefficients[i] = self.coefficients[i] + other.coefficients[i]
        self.length = len(self.coefficients)
        self.nonZero = np.count_nonzero(self.coefficients)
        return self

    def __sub__(self, other):
        for i in range(0,other.length):
            self.coefficients[i] = self.coefficients[i] - other.coefficients[i]
        self.length = len(self.coefficients)
        self.nonZero = np.count_nonzero(self.coefficients)
        return self

    def split(self):
        first_max_ind = int((self.length-1)/2)
        first_coefs = self.coefficients[:first_max_ind]
        first = Polynom(first_coefs)
        second_coefs = self.coefficients[first_max_ind:]
        second = Polynom(second_coefs)
        return first, second

def divideAndConquer(a,b):
    """simple divide and conquer algorithm for multiplication"""
    
    if a.nonZero == 2 and b.nonZero == 2:
        c = naiveMultiply(a,b)
        return c
    else:
        a0, a1 = a.split()
        b0, b1 = b.split()

        # calculate y, u, and z
        y = divideAndConquer(a0 + a1, b0 + b1)
        u = divideAndConquer(a0, b0)
        z = divideAndConquer(a1, b1)
        middleTerm = y - u - z
        
        NOver2 = int(max(a.length/2, b.length/2))
        lyst = [0] * int(NOver2 + 1)
        lyst[NOver2] = 1
        xNOver2 = Polynom(lyst)
        
        return u + naiveMultiply(middleTerm, xNOver2) + naiveMultiply(z, xNOver2)

def naiveMultiply(a,b):
    """takes two polynomials and multiplies using naive approach"""
    
    maxLength = a.length + b.length - 1
    coefficientList = [0] * maxLength
    
    for i in range(0,a.length):
        for j in range(0, b.length):
            power = i + j
            coefficient = a.coefficients[i] * b.coefficients[j]
            coefficientList[power] += coefficient
    
    return Polynom(coefficientList)

a = Polynom([1,2,3,4,5])
b = Polynom([1,2,3,4,5])

naiveMultiply(a,b)
divideAndConquer(a,b)
```

The correct answer for test case: (1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4)^2
should be:
1 + 4x + 10x^2 + 20x^3 + 35x^4 + 44x^5 + 46x^6 + 40x^7 + 25x^8

but I'm getting:
100 + 100x + 25x^2 + 0x^3 + 0x^4 + 0x^5

Comment: What's the definition of naiveMultiply?

Comment: Please provide an example for how to invoke the test case using the function provided, along with the def for `naiveMultiply` as requested by @Nick ODell

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but using a bare try-except to catch indexerrors in the `__add__` method is very unrecommended, and is likely to lead to bigger issues. Use a specific exception for that (or just check the array bounds).

Answer (score 2):

Your `__add__` and `__sub__` methods alter the `self` instance (note the assignments to `self.coefficients`).

Further down in the `divideAndConquer` method, I see that you are using a variable `a0` in an expression `a0 + a1`, which would alter the value of `a0` to become `a0 + a1`. You then use the same (altered) `a0` variable in further expressions, possibly not aware that the variable now has a different value.

In general, overloaded operator methods should probably create a new instance instead of altering `self`, this will make them much safer to use.

in this case, for example, a safe implementation of `__add__` would be

```
def __add__(self, other):
    coefficients = list(self.coefficients)
    for i in range(0,other.length):
        try:
            coefficients[i] = coefficients[i] + other.coefficients[i]
        except:
            coefficients.append(0)
            coefficients[i] = coefficients[i] + other.coefficients[i]
    return Polynom(coefficients)
```

(I've minimally fixed the self-altering; there are several further improvements that should be made to the method including what has been suggested in the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Pyton-level implementation bugs, there are also math-level bugs here: the polynomials are split down their own middles, but that creates a problem when putting the pieces back together. Also the `z` piece shouldn't be scaled by the same amount as the `middleTerm`.

This already *looks* suspicious anyway:

```
    NOver2 = int(max(a.length/2, b.length/2))
```

The goal with the calculation of `middleTerm` is that the *scaled* `middleTerm` (after shifting it) is identical to `a0 * b1 * scaleB + a1 * scaleA * b0` (where `scaleA` corresponds to the size of `a0`, and `scaleB` corresponds to the size of `b0`). If `scaleA == scaleB` then that's no problem, multiply by the scale afterwards (by shifting - if you implement this scaling as a `naiveMultiply` then the algorithm isn't efficient). But in this code, the scales are not necessarily the same, they depend on the sizes of `a` and `b`. That's a problem.

The `z` piece is the products of two "upper halves", so it picks up *two* of those scale factors. So it should be multiplied by the square of the factor that the middle term is scaled by, or rather, *shifted* by twice as much as the middle term is shifted by.